# Alternative name for downward kick?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, terminology

My WT dojang uses a different name for the downward kick (axe kick, hammer kick). Instead of naeryeo chagi (내려차기), we say something that to my Spanish-speaking brain sounds like chiko chagi. I've found a couple of references online, but none of them included the Hangul spelling. I'm curious, does anyone know about this other name and what the actual Korean word is, if it is at all Korean?

Comment: For reference, WT means "World Taekwondo". It used to be WTF (World Taekwondo Federation) before they shortened it.

Comment: Incidentally, I tried looking it up, but didn't get the Korean writing for it. The word is "chikyo chagi". I've seen it written as "chiko chagi" as well. I know naeryo chagi means "downward" kick in Korean. I'm not sure what chikyo chagi means exactly. To complicate matters, the "chi" sound may actually be "je" or "ji". I've tried translating a number of phrases like "dropping", "axe", "chopping", etc. into Korean, and nothing the translator comes up with sounds like chikyo. So that's where I gave up.

Comment: The only other vaguely similar explanation I could see was *Chigi Chagi*, but that would be "Strike Kick", which is a bit nonsensical (ran into *chigi* in a list of kicks, which noted that knee strikes use *chigi*).

Comment: @SteveWeigand, thank you for the input. I did find some results that said chikyo, but they all related to the Resident Evil franchise, so I didn't give them a lot of weight. I've also tried to reverse engineer the translation, using different combinations of chi, ji, jji for the first syllable and ko, kko, kyo, kkyo for the second one, but I couldn't generate anything that seemed to be a valid word...

Comment: The chikyo chagi comes from official Taekwondo sources. It's not just that Resident Evil thing. Haha. Roughly half of TKD sources use "chikyo chagi". The other half use "chiko chagi". And Spanish web sites use "chico chagi". Haha. Like Boy Kick. Kick that boy in the head! Wow. Haha.

Answer (score 1):

As Steve noted above, "Chikyo Chagi" ([possibly](https://www.reddit.com/r/taekwondo/comments/14yof3e/comment/jruahn0/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) *치쿄 차기*), also called "Chiko Chagi", is a term used for an axe kick in multiple TKD federations, although the provenance of the name is unknown (although there is a place in South Korea named [Chikyō-dō](https://www.getamap.net/maps/south_korea/kangwon-do/_chikyodo/) which could relate to the name).