# What is the origin of the kick name, "Chikyo Chagi"?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, terminology

Related to [Alternative name for downward kick?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/13712/alternative-name-for-downward-kick), what is the origin of the kick name, "Chikyo Chagi" (possibly *치쿄 차기*)? Is it named after the [Chikyō-dō](https://www.getamap.net/maps/south_korea/kangwon-do/_chikyodo/) region? Does it come from the Japanese Chikyo (*血居*), apparently translated as "blood house"?

Comment: In my limited experience of Japanese language.  Unless the characters match it's a different word.  They don't have a huge number of sounds.  Puns in Japanese very common and are a source of much superstition.  The reason you don't use 'shi' for counting most of the time for example is that it sounds like the word for death.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ***notoriously inaccurate Google translate***:

Chikyo 치쿄 translates to 'first time'.

Chagi 차기 on the other hand has no English translation from Japanese to English.

From this you might guess:  The first time this kick was done in that particular school, someone called Chagi did it.

https://japanese-names.info/last-name/chagi/

This link confirms that chagi can be a surname in Japan... However note that the characters are different:

チャギ

So I'm going to conclude that this is incorrect.

Probably what is going on is that this is a kick that you start a drill with.  Chagi 차기 is basically not a Japanese word so this is probably only used in martial arts which have a both a Japanese and Korean influence (Like Taekwondo).

地球けり or Chikyūkeri is Earth Kick!
Earth Kick in Korean is... 지구 차기 jigu chagi

As this is a downward kick this is probably the more accurate translation.

Comment: But 地球けり or Chikyūkeri is Earth Kick!

Comment: And Earth Kick in Korean is...
지구 차기
jigu chagi!

Comment: :) Thank you. This makes sense. I'm going to give it a day or two, but I like your answer.

Comment: Just wanted to add: 차기 comes from 차다 which is "to kick" in Korean. -다 is the infinitive form and the -기 is like a nounifier, the equivalent of turning it from "kicking" into "kick".